# Update row with value from previous row in a GROUP BY query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Imagine I have a table like so:

```
account_id  date      value
1           1/1/2015  5
1           1/3/2015  7
1           1/7/2015  8
3           1/2/2015  4
```

What if I wanted to do an ORDER BY DATE and GROUP BY account_id and update each row with the value of the row before it?

So the end result should be:

```
account_id  date      value  prev_value
1           1/1/2015  5     null
1           1/3/2015  7     5
1           1/7/2015  8     7
3           1/2/2015  4     null
```

Any good way to do that in a single query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[`lag(value anyelement [, offset integer [, default anyelement ]])`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)** window function will do it for you, which basically:

> returns ***value*** evaluated at the row that is ***offset*** rows before the
>   current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead
>   return default (which must be of the same type as value). Both offset
>   and default are evaluated with respect to the current row. If omitted,
>   offset defaults to 1 and default to null

```
WITH t(account_id,date,value) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'1/1/2015'::DATE,5),
  (1,'1/3/2015'::DATE,7),
  (1,'1/7/2015'::DATE,8),
  (3,'1/2/2015'::DATE,4)
)
SELECT
  *,
  lag(value,1) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS prev_value
FROM t
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Result:

```
 account_id |   date   | value | prev_value 
------------+----------+-------+------------
          1 | 1/1/2015 |     5 |           
          1 | 1/3/2015 |     7 |          5
          1 | 1/7/2015 |     8 |          7
          3 | 1/2/2015 |     4 |           
(4 rows)
```